# How to use an object in application.yaml and then use it with @value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

In my Spring Boot Project I want to use an object that I inizialized in my application.ymal in this way:

```
Prova: 
    route:
      destination:
        protocol: "https://"
        ip: "10.125.7.21"
        port: 654
        root: "/sporting/"
        username: "admin"
        password: "admin"
      sources:
        gets: >
          jbo/bla.pop,
          seen/fraphic.gf/caric
        posts: >
          text/crash/potre/figur.ks/save_rapa,
          seen/dfr34.ks/load
```

And I created the object Prova in this way:

```
    public class Prova{
        List <Route> route;       
       //GET & SET
    }
    
    public class Route {
        private Destination destination;
        private Source sources;
        //GET & SET
    }
    
    public class Destination {
        private String protocol;
        private String ip;
        private Integer port;
        private String root;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        //GET & SET
    }
    
    public class Source {
        List<String> gets;
        List<String> posts;
        //GET & SET
    }
```

And I want to use it in my class Service in this way:

```
@Value("${spring.Prova}")
private Prova prova;
```

But by doing so I get :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.prova' in value "${spring.prova}"
```

How Can I do to solve this problem??
Please help me

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not just passing this as a `URI`?

Comment: I'm trying to build it starting from the properties of the yaml file ... My main goal is to intercept a request starting from this information

Comment: Right, but why not `route: https://admin:admin@10.125.7.21:654/sporting/`?